# How to declare javascript object with constructor in clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

My code works with realm library and at some point it calls realm constructor:

```
(dependencies/realm. (clj->js options))
```

Realm was declared like this:

```
(def realm (js/require "realm"))
```

Right now I want to temporarily mock realm object to not make calls to library. I tried this approach:

```
(def realm  #js {:schemaVersion (fn [])
                 :close         (fn [])})
```

It worked well for mocking close() and schemaVersion() functions but I'm getting error `dependencies.realm is not a constructor`.

How can I add constructor declaration to realm object placeholder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript a constructor is a function. Instead, you should have a function that returns an object:

```
(def realm (fn [] #js {}))
```

I assume `schemaVersion` and `close` are static methods. You can add them later with:

```
(goog.object/extend realm #js {:schemaVersion (fn [])
                               :close         (fn [])})
```